# Magento 2.2.2 Javascript bundle file size only 1Mb

Tags: magento2, javascript, blank-theme

I enabled bundle javascript file, but i saw in my local js file is 3.7Mb and my dev site just 1.0Mb. Here is my config

```
'dev' => 
  array (
    'js' => 
    array (
      'merge_files' => '1',
      'minify_files' => '1',
      'enable_js_bundling' => '1',
    ),
    'css' => 
    array (
      'minify_files' => '1',
      'merge_css_files' => '1',
    ),
    'static' => 
    array (
      'sign' => '1',
    ),
  )
```

here is the result between my local vs dev site:
[image]

Code and config are same. File etc/view.xml inherit from Blank theme.

I dont know why file size is too different between 2 sites.

Could someone help me out to understand it?

As my understanding like Mageto 2.1.x, i will have bundle1.min.js bundle2.min.js... if my js file is big.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like on Your local you have Merge js enabled.

When You want to bundel js for 1MB each you need to:

1. Switch to developer mode
2. Stores=> Configurations=>Advanced=>Developer=>JavaScript Settings=>Merge js switch to No.
3. Go back to production mode to see result.